# Is there a way to copy launch profiles from one instance of Dart Editor to another?

Tags: dart

I download the latest version of Dart Editor each day and have to rebuild my launch profiles.  Is there a way I can do this by copying a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually follow the tip from http://www.dartlang.org/docs/editor/

Copying dart/workspace directory seems to work as well.

**Updating without losing preferences**

If you already have Dart Editor and want to keep its state, install the new Dart Editor on top of the old one. For example, put the new ZIP file beside the old one, and then use the command-line interface to unzip on top of the old files

Comment: Also from https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/WH5th5aAC3g%5B1-25%5D  "The launch profiles are stored in the workspace metadata, under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches . If you do not delete the workspace at every new install, the launches preserve. "